# MYSQL UPDATE on KEY - duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

Need some assistance in this query. I was doing 3 queries to perform what i just found out can be done with 1. But it keeps adding a new record instead of updating..

```
INSERT INTO vendors (vendor, name, tel, email, popularity) VALUES
('ibm','support','911','ibm@ibm.com','0')  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
vendor='ibm', name = 'support', tel = '911',email = 'ibm@ibm.com',
popularity = popularity+1
```

I have the  'id' column set as unique... Schema below.

```
CREATE TABLE `vendors` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`vendor` text NOT NULL,
`name` text NOT NULL,
`tel` text NOT NULL,
`email` text NOT NULL,
`popularity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is new for me but i have checked the syntax on the mysql site.. Can't see the problem.

Thanks

Comment: you syntax is probably perfect.

Comment: You have ID as unique, but you're not inserting the ID. Figure out what other column you want to be unique (email, perhaps?) and set that to unique as well.

Comment: dupe target, focus on the word `clash`

Comment: When creating the table, modify this Unique Key(`id`,`email`)

Comment: I would suggest NOT using ID to check for dupes, instead use `email`  and `tel` eg; things that don't normally change frequently   Create a 2 column unique index on those 2 columns and it should work as expected.

Comment: Erm... The ID is auto-incremented so i did not have this as insert... Does the query itself need to contain a column that is a key? To cause the 'clash'???